# CopyFile() on VxWorks

Tags: vxworks

What is simple API for copy file(s) on VxWorks (look like a CopyFile() on Windows API)?

Comment: Require copy file from vxworks application on runtime...

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are talking about working in the command shell, so the commands may look like:

```
-> ls // lists the current directory contents
Myfile1
Myfile2
YourFile2.txt
value = 0 = 0x0          //return status of the ls command - executed w/o errors*

-> copy "Myfile1","/YourDirectory/Myfile1"    // FORMAT: copy "src" , "dest"*
                                              // NB: src & dest argument must be strings*
value = 0 = 0x0                               // return status of copy command.

-> cd "/YourDirectory/"  // change default directory - notice the trailing slash (/)
value = 0 = 0x0          // return status of cd command

-> ls
xyzfile
Myfile1
value = 0 = 0x0
```

**I hope this helps**
HadziJo

Comment: Thanks, I need resolution for application on runtime

Answer (score 1):

Generally, anything that can be executed at the shell can be called from a program other than the shell.

```
status = copy("Myfile1", "/YourDirectory/Myfile1");
if (status == OK)  .....
```

You might look at the **man page** for  `xcopy` as well depending on the functionality you need.

Comment: There is cp() routine that copies a file. More information about file manipulation routines you can find in the VxWorks Kernel API Reference, library usrFsLib

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "cp" command on cmd shell (vxWorks 6.x), but that is not API, so probably doesn't answer your question exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The best method I found is `xcopy("fromPath", "toPath")`. It will recursively (including folders and subfolders) copy (duplicate) everything fromPath toPath.

check out the VxWork Manual: http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/usrFsLib.html#xcopy